# Magento - What happens when Ordered product is Disabled?

Tags: magento

What happens when an Ordered product is Disabled before the Order is Processed completely? Can this order still be processed?

Lets say, a product is ordered by a user. Then from Catalog I disabled this product (and the Order is still pending and not processed). Will the Order be effected in anyway? (I hope not).

Comment: I think it is quite easy to simulate these conditions and see what is happening. Why you just don't do it?

Comment: I thought someone may already know it ....